# JS: How to test the perfomance of a single function

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I wrote a JS function for an exercise and wanted to compare the performance of it with the given solution. 
I stumbled upon [this feature](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/99-line-level-profiling/) in Chrome but I couldn't get it to work like in the GIF.

I then searched in the performance tab in Chrome and found the desired function under "Evaluate script". Is that the value I'm searching for? If so is there a fancier way of looking into the performance of the function? I would really like to have it the same way as the GIF shows.

Comment: What happens if you try to reproduce those steps?

Comment: The time isn't being displayed in source tab. https://i.imgur.com/ZcOUYd5.gif

Comment: Was your code executes while the performance recording was running? It's likely that you need to trigger that manually, chrome won't do that for you.

Comment: I called the functions in the HTML file I'm browsing with Chrome, so I guess they should be triggered after I hit the "Start profiling and reload page" button. Or am I guessing wrong?